# How to use array pluck to get key values from a multidemensional array in Laravel?

Tags: arrays, laravel

I have the following multidemensional array:

```php
[
    {
        "city": {
            "name": "New York",
            "country": "Usa",
            "geolocation": {
                "lat": "40.7142691",
                "lon": "-74.0059729"
            },
        },
        "experiences": [
            {
                "title": "foobar",
                "id": "54095f19ca04fffa8791ecae"
            },
            {
                "title": "foobar_foo",
                "id": "54e1bff02f16a457c00ea171"
            }
            [...]
        ]
    },
    {
        "city": {
            "name": "San Francisco",
            "country": "Usa",
            "geolocation": {
                "lat": "37.7749295",
                "lon": "-122.4194155"
            },
        },
        "experiences": [
            {
                "title": "foobar",
                "id": "53e4db618027d69eab65f2ce"
            },
            {
                "title": "foobar_bar",
                "id": "54afbeb7abdf8e3d30bd5993"
            }
            [...]
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to create a new array filled with the IDs of each experience in the above array, something like:

```php
["id" = "foo123", "id" => "foo456", "id" => "foo789", "id" => "fooabc"]
```

I've tried using laravel's helper `Arr::pluck` but it returns null:

```php
Arr::pluck($myArr, "experiences.id")
```

*[null, null, null]*

How can I do this?

Comment: You need id's associated with city ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
$res = [];
foreach($data as $key => $value)
{
  foreach($value['experiences'] as $exp)
  {
    $res[] = $exp['id'];
  }
}
dd($res);
```

Output will be

```
array:4 [
0 => "54095f19ca04fffa8791ecae"
1 => "54e1bff02f16a457c00ea171"
2 => "53e4db618027d69eab65f2ce"
3 => "54afbeb7abdf8e3d30bd5993"
]
```